# Android: Using findViewById() with defined set of strings

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I read several blogs on stack overflow which had a solution to this topic issue. However, on implementing those solutions, being a beginner couldn't solve it and need help to sort this issue. Can we make an array of type EditText? Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    String[] referenceVariables = {"firstName", "lastName", "uid", "password", "reenterPassword", "emailId"};
    String[] reference = {"enterFirstName","enterLastName","enterUid","enterPassword","enterEmailId"};

    for(int i=0; i<reference.length;i++){
        int resID = (getResources().getIdentifier(reference[i], "id", getPackageName()));
        referenceVariables[i] = ((EditText) findViewById(resID));
    }
}
```

Ultimately what I want is this in optimized and short format :

```
firstName = findViewById(R.id.enterFirstName);
lastName = findViewById(R.id.enterLastName);
uid = findViewById(R.id.enterUid);
password = findViewById(R.id.enterPassword); 
reenterPassword = findViewById(R.id.reenterPassword);
emailId = findViewById(R.id.enterEmailId);
```

Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Comment: `referenceVariables[i] = ((EditText) findViewById(resID));` what you are trying to do with this line? `referenceVariables` is string array and `findViewById()` will return a view

Comment: `referenceVariable[i]` is a `String Array` but you are assigning an `EditText` to it. This is a blinding error.

Comment: @AbuYousuf I want to achieve this code: EditText XYZ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ABC); but in loop. Here, "XYZ" is reference variable and "ABC" is id of EditText in xml file. i.e. <EditText android:id="@+id/ABC"

Comment: save your time, prefer using https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: How String reference can hold a view object? its not possible

Comment: Change your `reference ` array to `view` type.

Answer (score 0):

`referenceVariables[i]` must be assigned to a String. You've assigned to an EditText, so that doesn't compile.

Yes, you can make an array of EditText or View objects

Try making this array

```
EditText[] texts = new EditText[reference.length]:
```

and assigning elements in it

If you want named elements, use a `HashMap<String, EditText>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)